# What is the valid selector type for `selector` property in angular2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm reading in a book about `selector` property of a component that:

> With the selector key, you indicate how your component will be
>   recognized when rendering HTML templates. The idea is similar to CSS
>   or XPath selectors. The selector is a way to define what elements in
>   the HTML will match this component. In this case, by saying selector:
>   'inventoryapp', we’re saying that in our HTML we want to match the
>   inventory-app tag, that is, we’re defining a new tag that has new
>   functionality whenever we use it.

So I put in CSS selector

```
@Component({
  selector: 'span[my-app].z',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
```

and it worked.

So I'm interested to know if the full CSS selectors syntax is supported.

Comment: Can you share your code on how you are using the selector?

Comment: @echonax, okay, it works, just a typo. But anyway, I'm still interested to know if the full CSS selectors syntax is supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

According to angular2 docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

**Directive configuration**:

```
selector: '.cool-button:not(a)'
```

> Specifies a CSS selector that identifies this directive within a template. Supported selectors include element, [attribute], .class, and :not().
>   Does not support parent-child relationship selectors.

Note: The usual way to define a component selector is just by giving it a tag as you know. Like: selector: `"my-component"` and use it as `<my-component>` inside the html.